# Fetch ID from Div tag using GTM

Tags: css-selectors, google-tag-manager

I am trying to find some text inside an element using a css selector. If not CSS selector, please help me with the method to do so. I am struggling and this is for a client project I need to deliver in a day.

```
<div class="order-detail-item OrderDoneIDtxt">
<h5>Order ID</h5>
<p>IFQ43518</p>
</div>
```

I want to fetch this Order ID under 'P' tag as a label in GTM. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a `Custom JavaScript` variable like this should do the trick:

```js
function() {
  return document.querySelector('.order-detail-item.OrderDoneIDtxt > p').innerText;
}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you for quickly solving this. I am new to it and it helped me complete the project.